# How to save pdf with TextBoxes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, pdf, gridview

I want to save my gridview in pdf.
The point is that all the cells, except the header row (columns title) and the first column (rows title), have to be **PDF textboxes**, so once I open the file I can write text inside.
How can I do it?
I have found that it is possibe to create a pdf with textfields but I have not found a way to make them in a specific part of the sheet.

I have tried to do so:  [Link 1](https://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/itextsharp-creating-form-fields/)

Comment: What have you tried?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: it seems too broad.

Comment: @Asif.Ali the question or the request?

Comment: your question *Now i want to export or save or print to pdf my gridview*.

Comment: @Asif.Ali yes because for me it is the same which one of this result i really, by the way I am editing the question .